# Salesforce DX - Managed packages

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to convert one of our managed packages to DX. I run into trouble when converting the Metadata Package into DX format using the command

```
sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r ./temp/
```

I get an error `no such file or directory` and it is obvious why - the Managed Package has a dependency on another of our managed packages, and the missing file is a reference to one in the other package.

Is DX compatible with managed packages with dependencies? What can I do about this?

The steps I have done so far are (Time is the name of the Managed Package):

#### Create DX project for Time

sfdx force:project:create -n Time

#### Use the Time Packaging Org as the DX Dev Hub

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a TimeHub
```

This will open the browser. Log in to Time as normal. Allow access when prompted.

#### Navigate to Time directory.

edit sfdx-project.json, set correct namespace

#### Download the package using the Metadata API

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./temp -p "Time" -u TimeHub
```

This downloads the package into a zip file at ./temp/unpackaged.zip

#### Convert the package into DX format. Unzip first.

```
unzip ./temp/unpackaged.zip -d ./temp/
sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r ./temp/
```

The final command to do the conversion fails with `file not found`.